# Using mobile data on sim card 1 and sim card 2 for calls and messages?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, sms, calls, mobile-data, dual-sim

Can I use both sim cards in order to use internet and handling calls? For example, while browsing on the internet on sim card 1, can I get calls to sim card 2 and also call to somebody else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> while browsing on the internet on sim card 1, can I get calls to sim card 2 and also call to somebody else?

You can call someone/receive calls in SIM 2, but you won't be able to use the internet from SIM 1 during the call. But if you call someone/receive a call on SIM 1, you can still use the internet from SIM 1 during the call.

Comment: Thanks, it's really disadvantage that I can't use internet during calls.